# Upload blob using WL.upload

Tags: upload, blob, onedrive

Using [this](http://isdk.dev.live.com/dev/isdk/ISDK.aspx?category=scenarioGroup_skyDrive&index=1) example I am trying to upload a file to OneDrive.

My issue is that I want to upload a Blob object, and the WL.upload method seems to only accept the Id of an `<input />` element.

Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest using the new OneDrive API (specifically https://dev.onedrive.com/items/upload.htm)

Comment: I have now implemented a solution with the api in your link. Would have been nice if the tool har worked. Thanks.